# How to close a chrome app immediately?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a [chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). The app has a dialog in which the user can close the application.

Internally the **chrome app** now closes all its application windows and waits for **chrome** to shut the application down. After closing the windows **chrome** usually takes about 10 sec or so before it `unloads`(aka: shuts down) the application and calls `chrome.runtime.onSuspend`. Only then also the `chrome://extensions/` dialog shows the application as `(inactive)`.

This is documented in the [chrome app lifecycle](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle).

**The problem** is that sometimes a user restarts the application right away and if you do remove all objects yourself cleanly this could be an issues - one example: all chrome app instances of the same application share their memory.
Hence it would be nice if I could just close a chrome-app and not having to worry about cleaning up every last object etc.

Comment: I don't understand the need to clean up every last object etc. Garbage collection will do this for you ... could you explain more? Does the structure of your app make it hard to release your references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is actually closing the `BackgroundPage`.

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(background) {
    background.close();
});
```

Besides closing the `BackgroundPage` you also need to close all other application windows, but then the application gets flagged as `inactive` right away.

Comment: This might work for your app, but in general it is a bad idea as it will cause APIs and things to abruptly stop working.

Comment: Which is fine. As I mentioned above, the chrome app lifecycle does not want you to close the app abruptly. But sometimes you still want to... and in this case my work around helps you do that.